# Repository doesn't generate in Doctrine 2

Tags: entity-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm working with Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine 2 and my application has two modules:

1. Privado (Private)
2. Publico (Public).

I created an Entity in Public, my first entity in public, and now I'm trying to create her repository using the command:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-repositories ./module/Publico/src/
```

And all the repositories from Private module are created but the repository from my new entity in Public module is not created.

[image]

So, what happened?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, I have been make a terrible mistake. I don't define correctly the Repository class.

**Wrong:**

```
/** @ORM\Entity
*  @ORM\Table(name="menu")
*   @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Privado\Repository\EstadoRepository")
*/
```

**Right:**

```
/** @ORM\Entity
*  @ORM\Table(name="menu")
*   @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Publico\Repository\MenuRepository")
*/
```

Comment: For completeness José, you can "self-accept" this answer, by clicking the tick mark to the left of it, so that it turns green. Would you do that now?